# Does @Transactional(rollbackFor = { SomeRuntimeException.class }) in Spring cause other RuntimeExceptions to be excluded?

Tags: java, spring, transactions

Suppose I have a method annotated with `@Transactional`, without the `rollbackFor` attribute:

```java
@Transational
public void doSomething() {
    ...
}
```

The docs say that when `rollbackFor` is not specified, then if any `RuntimeException` or `Error` occurs, the transaction is rolled back.

From the [`Transactional.rollbackFor()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html#rollbackFor()) docs:

> By default, a transaction will be rolled back on `RuntimeException` and `Error` but not on checked exceptions (business exceptions). See `DefaultTransactionAttribute.rollbackOn(Throwable)` for a detailed explanation.

From the [`DefaultTransactionAttribute.rollbackOn(Throwable)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/interceptor/DefaultTransactionAttribute.html#rollbackOn(java.lang.Throwable)) docs:

> The default behavior is as with EJB: rollback on unchecked exception (RuntimeException), assuming an unexpected outcome outside any business rules. Additionally, we also attempt to rollback on Error which is clearly an unexpected outcome as well.

Now suppose I have a custom subclass of `RuntimeException` called `SomeRuntimeException`, And I add the `rollbackFor` attribute:

```java
@Transactional(rollbackFor = { SomeRuntimeException.class })
public void doSomething() {
    ...
}
```

Does that mean that any other `RuntimeException`, like `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` or even `NullPointerException`, will cause the transaction to be committed? (I think not, but I'm not sure whether there are any exceptions to this.)

Anyhow, what's the point of adding any subclass of `RuntimeException` to the array of `rollbackFor` values?

Comment: All unchecked exceptions will trigger the rollback, but if for some reason you want to rollback with a checked exception you can do it with the rollbackFor, for example you have a custom exception when you do not find a specific database user, you can put it in your `rollbackFor` and every time you have it the rollback will occur.

Comment: There isn't any point, there is only a point using `noRollbackFor` for specific `RuntimeException`'s or `rollbackFor` to include certain checked exceptions. It will still rollback all `RuntimeException` that occur.

Comment: It will keep rolling back for all runtime unchecked exceptions and errors. Only thing you did by this code @Transactional(rollbackFor = { SomeRuntimeException.class }), that you ensure that when you raise this exception, it rolls back.